# Getting notification when device enters/ leaves WiFi

Tags: wifi-configuration, notifications, fritzbox

I would like to know about possibilities to get notified (push notification on my mobile or an email) whenever a certain device connects to/ disconnects from my WiFi.
I´m using a fritzbox.
Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can try the fritz!box "Push Services" set up your email and the trigger for every new event.
2. You could set up a Windows or Linux machine with periodic network scans.

   - For example a *RaspberryPI* with *Nmap*. Schedule a script with crontab to run every minute [1](https://nmap.org/book/ndiff-man-periodic.html). This script should scan your network with *Nmap* and post the output of that scan to *Ndiff*. *Ndiff* is a *Nmap* utility which compares two Nmap scans and checks for differences [2](https://nmap.org/ndiff/). If there is a difference your script will then send you an email with the latest scan.